# setURL:forPersistentStore: not required even if I changed the location of .sqlite file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, core-data

I am using Core Data for persistence in my app. Above that I am using custom migration and creating a new sqlite file. I had named my sqlite file as **project.sqlite** in version 1 of app and after custom migration I have named new sqlite file as **projectNew.sqlite**. After custom migration of data, I remove my old sqlite file and rename the new sqlite file with old name i.e delete ***project.sqlite*** and rename *projectNew.sqlite* to ***project.sqlite***

```
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                  configuration:nil
                                                            URL:storeUrl
                                                        options:options
                                                          error:&error])
    {
        DLog(@"%@",error);
    }
    else
    {    

        NSString* newDBfile = [storePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"projectNew.sqlite"];
        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newDBfile];

        if (fileExists) {

            NSString* oldDBfile = [storePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"project.sqlite"];

            if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:oldDBfile error:&error] != YES)
            {
                NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            NSString *newPath = [storePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"project.sqlite"];

            // Attempt the move
            if ([fileManager moveItemAtPath:newDBfile toPath:newPath error:&error] != YES)
            {
                NSLog(@"Unable to move file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

         if (![persistentStoreCoordinator setURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath] forPersistentStore:[persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStoreForURL:storeUrl]]) 
          {
            DLog(@"Persistent store not changed");
          }

}
```

This whole process is successful even without a call to `setURL:forPersistentStore:` (last line of my code)
which I think is a necessary step as my DB file location has changed but persistentStoreCoordinator is not yet updated. Can anyone tell how persistentStoreCoordinator is getting updated itself or why the code is working?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because the sqlite file is already open. Under Unix, any existing file handles remain valid after you move a file to a new location (and will correctly read/write at the new location), assuming the same file system.

The danger though, is that it's not necessarily just the .sqlite file - sqlite also uses other files like WAL files alongside which will still have their old names (which is a problem if you plan to overwrite them).